# 'str' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I'm looking to return the words of a file in lowercase without punctuation.

despite having directories `str` and `bytes` I'm unable to import either in my code without getting an import error. Importing string works even though the python interpreter says "name 'string' is not defined"

```py
def text_to_words(the_text):
    """ return a list of words with all punctuation removed,
        and all in lowercase.
    """

    my_substitutions = the_text.maketrans(
      # If you find any of these
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~'\\",
      # Replace them by these
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz                                          ")

    # Translate the text now.
    cleaned_text = the_text.translate(my_substitutions)
    wds = cleaned_text.split()
    return wds
```

this throws up the titular error as opposed to the translation.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: How are you calling this function? What exactly is `the_text`?

Comment: And why are you trying to import directories named "str" and "bytes"? These are built-in types.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of python. I wasn't originally trying to import either bytes or str and was still getting the error. The text is a .txt file.

Comment: @JakeWiseman-Lovett latest  version of python is 3.7 but your error suggests you're using python-2.x?

Comment: when I open the interpreter I get Python 3.7.2 @mx0

Comment: @JakeWiseman-Lovett you'll have to show rest of your code (reading a file and calling this function). Function `text_to_words(the_text)` expects a `string` as an argument but you're probably sending something else.

Comment: `def get_words_in_book(filename):
    
    f = open(filename, "r")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    wds = text_to_words(content)
    return wds`

http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/_downloads/alice_in_wonderland.txt

Comment: @JakeWiseman-Lovett Please edit your question with all relevant information you gave in comments.

Answer (score 1):

In **python 2.x** you have to import `maketrans` first, it's in `string` module:

```
from string import maketrans
```

Then change line where you create translation table:

```
my_substitutions = maketrans( ... )
```

In **python 3.x** `maketrans` is already defined for `str` so you don't have to import it.

You can always check what methods are available with:

```
dir(str)
```